# R Time Series with Date Frequency

Tags: r, csv, time-series

I'm trying to create a time series graph uses data from a csv file with a format like the table below.

```
Date                   Crime
2015-12-17 07:26:00    Vandalism
2015-12-17 11:04:00    Theft 
2015-06-18 12:32:00    Murder
.
.
.
```

I want to show the frequency of all crimes every day over the course of the year. And I also want to be able to show the frequency per type of crime. I'm kinda new to R so I was wondering what would be the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your dataframe is pure text since you read it from a csv file.  You can share it with us using the `dput` command.  Here's one I prepared earlier:

```
df = structure(list(
    Date = c("2015-12-17 07:26:00", "2015-12-17 11:04:00", "2015-06-18 12:32:00"), 
    Crime = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Murder", "Theft", "Vandalism"), class = "factor")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L), .Names = c("Date", "Crime"))
```

You can convert the `Date` column to an actual date using `lubridate`'s `ymd_hms` command:

```
library(lubridate)
df$Date = ymd_hms(df$Date)
```

Then you can convert the Date-Time construct into a pure day:

```
df$Date = as.Date(df$Date)
```

Now you can aggregate by `Date` and `Crime` in the usual way.  Here's the `dplyr` way:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Date, Crime) %>% summarise(count = n())
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Date [?]
        Date     Crime count
      <date>    <fctr> <int>
1 2015-06-18    Murder     1
2 2015-12-17     Theft     1
3 2015-12-17 Vandalism     1
```